# Laravel 5.1 - Model observer on relative models

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.1, observers

Let's suppose I have the following related tables:

```
pages
----------------
id 
content

visitors
----------------
id
name

page_visitor
----------------
page_id
visitor_id
```

As you see can we have three tables, in which `pages` and `visitors` have a many-to-many relationship.

I have successfully implemented an observer class on the `pages` model class, and now, what ever I do to the pages table gets reflected somewhere else. Using the following code:

```
class ElasticsearchPageObserver
{
    private $elasticsearch;

    public function __construct(ESClient $client)
    {
        $this->elasticsearch = $client;
    }

    public function created(Page $page)
    {
        $params = $page->buildElasticsearchParams();
        $response = $this->elasticsearch->index($params);
    }

    public function updated(Page $page)
    {
        $params = $page->buildElasticsearchParams();
        $response = $this->elasticsearch->index($params);
    }
}
```

You get the idea, right?

As it turns out, when the tables that have a one-to-many relationship with the page table get updated, the above observer, observes it. But not for many-to-many relationships(like the above).

Well, now how do I go about this??? How to do the same thing when `page_visitor` gets updated?

Thanks

Comment: Well apparently there's no way. I have to create a method inside `page` and call it whenever I wanna attach to any other model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a method to use instead of calling `attach` on every related class.

```
// in page:
public function attachTo($to, $id)
    {
        switch($to) {
            case 'App\Models\Visitor':
                $this->visitors()->attach($id);
                break;
            case 'App\Models\Banner':
                $this->banners()->attach($id);
                break;
            case 'App\Models\AdBlock':
                $this->adblocks()->attach($id);
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
        $this->indexInElasticsearch();
    }
```